# Custom Bottom Navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

[image][image]

I am trying to achieve shape like above image. I only able to achieve like below image. I used **curved_navigation_bar** dependency for navigation bar. Onclick of each icon highlighted view has to move to next.  Thanks in advance

[image]

Code :

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(


  body:
 Stack(
   children: [
     Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         image: DecorationImage(
           image: AssetImage("assets/background_splash.png"),
           fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
       ),

     ),

     Align(
       alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
       child:   CurvedNavigationBar(
         height: 55,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
         items: <Widget>[
           Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
           Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
           Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
           Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
           Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
         ],
         onTap: (index) {
           //Handle button tap
         },
       ),
     )

   ],
 ),
 );
 }
```

Dependency :

```
dependencies:
 curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.4
```

Comment: You can do that using CustomPainter. Watch this tutorial which exactly creates that bottom navigation bar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA&ab_channel=RetroPortalStudio

Comment: but i need On click highlighted view has to move with animation in that video it has fixed

Comment: See the other videos in that channel that has another one which has this functionality. Please try to implement/research then tell us what is not working for you. Nobody will write free code here, but everybody will help you to solve the issues in **your** code.

Comment: Sorry I did not expect free code here. I came here for suggestion or if any lib available . I have seen that video already but could not get exact functionality.  That's why I asked question. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that. I mean if you try those suggestion and when you get stuck please ask a question with relevant code, which can get you better answers and it will be easy for us to help you. In the current format it's very difficult to answer (too broad). If you see this library https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar which also uses custom paint to draw the navigation bar (From your code I assume you are using this library to create the bar). Try to create your own custom paint like the one mentioned in the video and replace it. You can see the packages code in it's github repo

Comment: Yes that's what I did. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This code will be help you.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA&ab_channel=RetroPortalStudio

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      
      void main() {
        runApp(MyApp());
      }
      
      class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
        // This widget is the root of your application.
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Bottom Nav Bar V2',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ),
            home: BottomNavBarV2(),
          );
        }
      }
      
      class BottomNavBarV2 extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        _BottomNavBarV2State createState() => _BottomNavBarV2State();
      }
      
      class _BottomNavBarV2State extends State<BottomNavBarV2> {
        int currentIndex = 0;
      
        setBottomBarIndex(index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        }
      
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(55),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    height: 80,
                    child: Stack(
                      overflow: Overflow.visible,
                      children: [
                        CustomPaint(
                          size: Size(size.width, 80),
                          painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          heightFactor: 0.6,
                          child: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Colors.orange, child: Icon(Icons.home), elevation: 0.1, onPressed: () {}),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: size.width,
                          height: 80,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.home,
                                  color: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setBottomBarIndex(0);
                                },
                                splashColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.restaurant_menu,
                                    color: currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setBottomBarIndex(1);
                                  }),
                              Container(
                                width: size.width * 0.20,
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.bookmark,
                                    color: currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setBottomBarIndex(2);
                                  }),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.notifications,
                                    color: currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setBottomBarIndex(3);
                                  }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
      
      class BNBCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
        @override
        void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
          Paint paint = new Paint()
            ..color = Colors.white
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
      
          Path path = Path();
          path.moveTo(0, 20); // Start
          path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.25, 0, size.width * 0.35, 0);
          path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.40, 0, size.width * 0.40, 20);
          path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.60, 20), radius: Radius.circular(20.0), clockwise: false);
          path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.60, 0, size.width * 0.65, 0);
          path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.75, 0, size.width, 20);
          path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
          path.lineTo(0, size.height);
          path.lineTo(0, 20);
          canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 5, true);
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
      
        @override
        bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: You should have attributed/mentioned the actual author or their post in your answer

Comment: This i have seen  but On click highlighted view has to move with animation. I have updated my question.